# OleDb DataSet Update

Tags: sql-server-ce, oledb

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server CE database via OleDB. So till the moment that I fill DataSet with data everything is ok, I got data there, but when it comes to update I get an error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]

No numbers suggesting where, and I can't figure out what is going on.

Can anyone help?

```
OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(connString); //no problem here
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from table", conn); //this query it doesn't like, but it syas that when it comes to update
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName); // here it has problems
```

Answer (score 0):

Using OLEDB with SQL Server Compact from .NET is not supported, you should use the ADO.NET provider (`System.Data.SqlServerCe`) - why do you use the OleDb provider?

Comment: I need to connect with sybase, take data from there and then fill with it my own database. Then someone else will run his program on it.